# Training costs reimbursements

Tags: salary

I recently resigned from my current position where I am contracted to work two months’ notice. Its written into my contract that I need to pay back training costs as a percentage which will reduce after 6 months with nothing to pay after 12. This total time of reimbursement is known as the “period” which starts from the end of the training.

I handed in my notice exactly two months before the 12 months “period”. I will continue to train their staff until the day I leave.

Should the repayment “period” be calculated from 10 month when I handed in my notice or from the time I finished the training to the day I leave the company? There is nowhere in the contract that states the period won't include any notice period given.

It could be the difference between having to pay back 5K or not and the company will make me pay if they can!

Comment: Why do you believe notice period is not included? Are you stopping work?

Comment: For those voting to close as company specific or legal advice, this is quite a common problem, easily answered, and very relevant to the workplace. The rules around this issue are quite standard and very company independant

Answer (score 3):

If you will finish on the exact day the contract expires, you will be in the clear. You can clarify this with your HR department, always safe to get it in writing.

In the end the contract about re-payment will include all of your working days, irrelevant of if you were on your notice period or not, unless the contract states otherwise. You've said there's no mention of a notice period not being included, therefore it is included as you're still working.

I mean, it's not like you've handed in your notice period and you're suddenly going to stop working. So you're in effect still paying the company with the work supplied.

The only thing I would confirm, is to make sure you've got your dates right, speak to your HR team and ask for a confirmation of when the day is that the contract expires. It's always best to cover your back!

Answer (score 3):

I would expect the repayment period to be calculated on the date you actually finish working there - not on the day you gave notice.

That said policies like this are not universal in the way they operate. I would read that section of your contract **carefully** to see what it says as it's possible they have written it in such a way as to calculate it from point of notice. I think it's unlikely to be the case though.